# SQL Reporting service unable to start after restoring on new hardware

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

I have a SQL server that the hardware is failing. As a solution we restored the image of the server on a multicore (more less new) server. The problem is that SQL 2000 cannot be started if number of CPUs is not in power of 2. I found this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2009/05/27/info-sql-2000-msde-installation-will-fail-if-you-have-number-of-cpus-on-a-box-which-is-not-in-power-of-2.aspx) that helped me with a nice trick to load SQL just fine but the reporting service is having the same issue.

So I am looking for a solution on how to load the Reporting Services on this new hardware. Here is the log of the Report Server Service.

---

```
<Header>
<Product>Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Version 8.00.1038.00</Product>
<Locale>en-US</Locale>
<TimeZone>SA Western Standard Time</TimeZone>
<Path>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL\Reporting Services\LogFiles\ReportServerService__06_05_2014_13_45_41.log</Path>
<SystemName>S*******R</SystemName>
<OSName>Microsoft Windows NT 5.2.3790.0</OSName>
<OSVersion>5.2.3790.0</OSVersion>
</Header>

ReportingServicesService!library!e24!6/5/2014-13:45:41:: i INFO: Initializing ConnectionType to '0' as specified in Configuration file.
ReportingServicesService!library!e24!6/5/2014-13:45:41:: i INFO: Initializing IsSchedulingService to 'True' as specified in Configuration file.
ReportingServicesService!library!e24!6/5/2014-13:45:41:: i INFO: Initializing IsNotificationService to 'True' as specified in Configuration file.
ReportingServicesService!library!e24!6/5/2014-13:45:41:: i INFO: Initializing IsEventService to 'True' as specified in Configuration file.
ReportingServicesService!library!e24!6/5/2014-13:45:41:: i INFO: Initializing PollingInterval to '10' second(s) as specified in Configuration file.
ReportingServicesService!library!e24!6/5/2014-13:45:41:: i INFO: Initializing MemoryLimit to '60' percent as specified in Configuration file.
ReportingServicesService!library!e24!6/5/2014-13:45:41:: i INFO: Initializing RecycleTime to '720' minute(s) as specified in Configuration file.
ReportingServicesService!library!e24!6/5/2014-13:45:41:: i INFO: Initializing MaximumMemoryLimit to '80' percent as specified in Configuration file.
ReportingServicesService!library!e24!6/5/2014-13:45:41:: i INFO: Initializing MaxAppDomainUnloadTime to '30' minute(s) as specified in Configuration file.
ReportingServicesService!library!e24!6/5/2014-13:45:41:: i INFO: Initializing MaxQueueThreads to '0' thread(s) as specified in Configuration file.
ReportingServicesService!library!e24!6/5/2014-13:45:41:: i INFO: Initializing MaxActiveReqForOneUser to '20' requests(s) as specified in Configuration file.
ReportingServicesService!library!e24!6/5/2014-13:45:41:: i INFO: Initializing MaxScheduleWait to '5' second(s) as specified in Configuration file.
ReportingServicesService!library!e24!6/5/2014-13:45:41:: i INFO: Initializing DatabaseQueryTimeout to '120' second(s) as specified in Configuration file.
ReportingServicesService!library!e24!6/5/2014-13:45:41:: i INFO: Initializing InstanceName to 'MSSQLSERVER' as specified in Configuration file.
ReportingServicesService!library!e24!6/5/2014-13:45:41:: i INFO: Initializing ProcessRecycleOptions to '0' as specified in Configuration file.
ReportingServicesService!library!e24!6/5/2014-13:45:41:: i INFO: Initializing RunningRequestsScavengerCycle to '60' second(s) as specified in Configuration file.
ReportingServicesService!library!e24!6/5/2014-13:45:41:: i INFO: Initializing RunningRequestsDbCycle to '60' second(s) as specified in Configuration file.
ReportingServicesService!library!e24!6/5/2014-13:45:41:: i INFO: Initializing RunningRequestsAge to '30' second(s) as specified in Configuration file.
ReportingServicesService!library!e24!6/5/2014-13:45:41:: i INFO: Initializing CleanupCycleMinutes to '10' minute(s) as specified in Configuration file.
ReportingServicesService!library!e24!6/5/2014-13:45:41:: i INFO: Initializing SecureConnectionLevel to '0' as specified in Configuration file.
ReportingServicesService!library!e24!6/5/2014-13:45:41:: i INFO: Initializing DisplayErrorLink to 'True' as specified in Configuration file.
ReportingServicesService!library!e24!6/5/2014-13:45:41:: i INFO: Initializing WebServiceUseFileShareStorage to default value of 'False' because it was not specified in Configuration file.
ReportingServicesService!servicecontroller!e24!6/5/2014-13:45:41:: Error Starting Service: System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.ResourceUtilities.BitsSet(Int32 nr)
at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.ResourceUtilities.ThrottleCpu()
at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Globals.InitializeProcessParameters()
at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ServiceController.StartService()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue my selecting the amount of cores on the server using the HP ROM based utilities. Instead of using all 12 cores from each CPU (a total of 24), I downgraded to 8 per CPU for a total of 16. Since it is a power of 2, problem solved. Thanks!